# Why does filtering out ASCII value 32 (' ') from a stringstream with the following function also filter out '\n' and '\t'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have been practicing different ways to filter out undesired garbage characters from a nlohmann::json object to an std::string, and I just finished the following function giving me a pretty good result (ignoring that I'm writing beginner sloppy code of course):

```
//This string is what I'm testing with as input.
std::string initial = "EA/1\n             \n                $9.34\n            \n                ";

std::string filter(std::string s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    char c;
    std::string final_string = "";
    while (ss >> c) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            char temp_c = c;
            while (ss >> c) {
                if (c == ' ') {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    final_string += temp_c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            final_string += c;
        }
    }
    return final_string;
}

//this is string that is produced when s is returned to main
result = "EA/1 $9.34"
```

I'm not sure why '\n' and '\t' are also filtered out even though I was only targeting ' ' in this step of testing. I can provide a photo of the breakdown of what exactly Visual Studio 2019 shows as being in `initial` if needed. Any insights would be most helpful as I'll be working on other strings with similar makeups for the next few days.

EDITED: I have changed the variable that is returned from function from `s` to `final_string`. Sorry for the confusion.

EDITED2: I chose Remy Lebeau's answer because it led me to realizing that my filtering was indeed not working at all which has taught me to more thoroughly debug before taking up y'all's time. The result I came to SO with was exactly what I wanted which led me to believe that my code was somehow more effective, hence my confusion. I'll know better now haha. Anyways, Remy's answer helped me resolve what I was wondering and gave me good advice for moving forward.

Comment: Hint. Try to use a debugger. Is the condition `(c == ' ')` met at least once?

Comment: [`ss >> std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) ? Besides that, you're returning the same string you were passed? I don't suppose that was considered?

Comment: `std::copy_if` does what you want.

Comment: @S.M. not by itself, it doesn't. You would have to pair it with `std::back_inserter()`, for instance.  It also wouldn't handle the case where the OP's code is using the inner loop to minimize runs of 2+ spaces into 1 space

Comment: erase-remove idiom would be better.

Comment: @sweenish If the OP just wanted to toss out *all* the spaces remove-erase would make this trivial indeed, but remove-erase won't do what the OP is asking, namely reducing all *consecutive* spaces into a single space.

Comment: Sure, I only glanced the code, and the question text made zero mention of it the actual task being done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```cpp
while (ss >> c) {
    if (c == ' ') {
```

The `if` will NEVER evaluate as `true`, because `operator>>` skips leading whitespace by default, which includes spaces, tabs, and line breaks.  So `c` will never be a whitespace character like `' '`.

Either:

- use [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws), like @WhozCraig suggested in comments:

```cpp
while (ss >> std::noskipws >> c)
```

- use [`std::istream::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), which does not skip whitespace:

```cpp
while (ss.get(c))
```

---

That being said,  there are other bugs in you code.

You are returning the unmodified `s` instead of the prepared `final_string`.

It looks like your inner `while` loop is *trying* to minimize runs of 2+ spaces into 1 space for output. Which is fine, except that is losing the character that ends a detected run.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
std::string filter(const std::string &s) {
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    char c;
    std::string final_string;
    while (iss.get(c)) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            while (iss.get(c)) {
                if (c != ' ') {
                    final_string += ' ';
                    final_string += c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            final_string += c;
        }
    }
    return final_string;
}
```

Lastly, when building up a new `std::string` in this manner, it is generally more efficient to use an `std::ostringstream` instead of `operator+=` (unless you `reserve()` the `std::string` up front), eg:

```cpp
std::string filter(const std::string &s) {
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    char c;
    std::ostringstream final_string;
    while (iss.get(c)) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            while (iss.get(c)) {
                if (c != ' ') {
                    final_string << ' ' << c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            final_string << c;
        }
    }
    return final_string.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the std::stringstream::operator>>() function. I am sure '\n', '\t', and space is escaped in the function. The following code will output the same result that you got already.

```
while (ss >> c) {
        
    final_string += c;
}
return final_string
```

It will be better to use basic code rather than stringstream as the following.

```
std::string filter(std::string s) {
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    std::string final_string = "";
    do{
        c = s[i];
        if (c != ' ') {
            final_string += c;
        }
        i++;
    } while (c != 0);
    return final_string;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, until I re-read the OP's code and realized that it is not stripping ALL space characters, only (trying to, unsuccessfully) to minimize runs of 2+ spaces into 1 space.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the intent is to compress consecutive runs of tabs and spaces to a single space, but retain new-lines, I'd probably do things a bit differently.

```cpp
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>

class my_ctype : public std::ctype<char> {
    mask my_table[table_size];
public:
    my_ctype(size_t refs = 0) : std::ctype<char>(&my_table[0], false, refs){
        std::copy_n(classic_table(), table_size, my_table);
        my_table['\n'] = mask();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::stringstream input("EA/1\n             \n                $9.34\n            \n                ");
    std::locale ss(std::locale::classic(), new my_ctype);
    input.imbue(ss);

    std::string word;
    while (input >> word)
      std::cout << '"' << word << "\"\n";
}
```

This bases its operation on the fact that a stream already uses a locale to figure out whether characters are white-space, and uses that to decide what to read into a string. So here we take advantage of that, and just modify it slightly to classify new-lines as not being white space so they'll be retained in the output. Other than that, the stream already does pretty much what we want, knowing how to ignore consecutive runs of white space, so we just make use of that instead of duplicating it.